# Prove that $\sin (2 \arcsin x) = 2 x \sqrt{1 - x^2}$

Tags: trigonometry

This is coming up in the computation of the integral of $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$. I have the result from Wolfram|Alpha, but I have no idea how to get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$,

$$\sin(2\arcsin x) = 2 \sin (\arcsin x) \cos(\arcsin x) = 2x \sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Where $\cos (\arcsin x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ can be obtained by drawing a right triangle.

Comment: Or trig. 1 $\sin^2(\arcsin(x)) + \cos^2(\arcsin(x)) =1$

Comment: Actually @eepperly16, $\cos\arcsin x=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ relies, other than the identity $\cos^2+\sin^2\equiv 1$, on the very important fact that $\arcsin x\in \left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$.